# SQL-SERVER - CASE error - CASE in specific source doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, case

I am working on a query where i want the average temperature of a whole month, but i have a challenge. When the new year starts the Month is 1 and i can't use the command:

```
MONTH(TimestampUTC) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Because month 1 minus 1 is month 0.

Therefor i wan't to use a case expression to make my code work.

When i run the query below i get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Ofcourse i want the following query to work. Can someone help me?

```
SELECT AVG(Value) AS AVG_temp 
FROM(

SELECT Value, TimestampUTC  
WHERE SourceName = 'Buitentemperatuur' 
CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(TimestampUTC) = 1 
    THEN MONTH(TimestampUTC) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, +11, GETDATE()))
        and YEAR(TimestampUTC) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))
    ELSE
        MONTH(TimestampUTC) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
        and YEAR(TimestampUTC) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()))
END 
FROM vDataLogChannelValue
) x
```

The program i work in is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.
I already did some UNIT tests on the other parts of the code. When i add the CASE the error comes active and the code doesn't work anymore.

UPDATE:

Thank you for the respons it works now, but now i have the following warning which doesn't make sense to me, because it worked when i tested it when it wasn't in this query:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>
> Incorrect syntax near '='.

It is about the following line:

```
THEN MONTH(TimestampUTC) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, +11, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Should there an `AND` between `'Buitentemperatuur'` and `CASE`?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to have an `AND` keyword after the first `WHERE` clause. And then you will have to build another `WHERE` clause which uses the `CASE` statement.
Apart from that there should be now assignments in the `THEN` clauses.

Here is an example of what could work in terms of syntax:

```
SELECT Value, TimestampUTC  
WHERE SourceName = 'Buitentemperatuur' AND SomethingElse =
CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(TimestampUTC) = 1 
    THEN 123
    ELSE
        234
END 
FROM vDataLogChannelValue
) x
```